# Scroll bar in browse not working

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I am not able to scroll the scroll bar in the browse to view more results. How can I achieve this?

```
DEFINE QUERY BROWSE-4 FOR Customer.
DEFINE BROWSE BROWSE-4 QUERY BROWSE-4 NO-LOCK DISPLAY custNum name /* ENABLE name */ WITH NO-ROW-MARKERS SEPARATORS SIZE 32 BY 6.46 FIT-LAST-COLUMN. .

open query browse-4 for each customer no-lock.

enable browse-4.

wait-for window-close of current-window.
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: i am not able to scroll the scroll bar in the browse to view results,how can i scroll the scroll bar and view the results below displayed

Comment: What version and OS?

Comment: sir i am using 10.2b version and os is windows 8.1-thank you

Comment: Works for me on 11.4 in Windows 7 so it might be a bug in a very old version... I have no possibility to test in 10.2B.

Comment: sir,in my system also it is working in normal query with browse,but if i use freeform query in browse means it is not working,please suggest me any thing alternate.-thankyou

Comment: Perhaps you need to clarify exactly what you're asking about. It isn't clear to me at least.

Comment: OPEN QUERY {&SELF-NAME} PRESELECT EACH ttevaluation.

Comment: sir just now i posted my query, my requirement is i have to display results from temp-table by using browse,in that browse the scroll bar is not working for viewing the complete results. so please tell me how could i enable that scroll bar to working state.-thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Just replace "FOR" with "PRESELECT" in the query:

```
DEFINE QUERY BROWSE-4 FOR Customer SCROLLING.
DEFINE BROWSE BROWSE-4 QUERY BROWSE-4 NO-LOCK DISPLAY custNum name /* ENABLE name */ WITH NO-ROW-MARKERS SEPARATORS SIZE 32 BY 6.46 FIT-LAST-COLUMN. .

open query browse-4 PRESELECT each customer no-lock.

enable browse-4.

wait-for window-close of current-window.
```

Just note that performance wise it can be a bad idea, as you are reading all the table contents at once...